# Questions to ask when using a professional printing service

Tags: photoshop, printing, color-management, prints, canvas-prints

I do lots of landscape photography. A friend of mine wants one of my photographs printed; I've never done this before! All of my photos are post-processed in Photoshop, and I only generate JPEG's for web use, never print.

I'll be hitting up a local print shop this week, what questions are important to ask when it comes to printing? I came up with a few...

1. What file format produces the best print? (PSD, JPG, etc.)
2. What type of paper should I request (matte, gloss, etc)
3. How can I ensure the print looks just like the digital format? Do I need to
   supply a color profile, or do print shops handle this minor color
   adjustments?
4. What type of ink should I request?

Did I miss anything? Again, I just need a print, the framing will be handled later.

Comment: This is kinda my question too, but just to make it clear, are you talking about [large format inkjet printers](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Print+Technology_Thermal+InkJet&ci=18353&N=4164498142+4166371313+4166371311)?

Comment: Not sure what print shops use, but I need a 36x20 print, I guess that qualifies for large print

Comment: Consider checking out one of the many pro labs that make actual photographic prints and not inkjet prints.

Comment: @Blrfl - im not aware of a digital photographic system capable of printing that size. but for general smaller prints they can be very good value.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios:  I have my printing done at [White House Custom Color](http://www.whcc.com).  They have a Durst Theta 76 that can print any size up to 30x144".  WHCC's closest non-custom size is 24x36".

Comment: @Blrfl - Ah ok fair enough! i wasnt aware of that machine - nice :-) - i never got into that side of things due to costs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK... I used to run a print shop so i think i qualify to answer this.

Any print shop that can print 36x20 inhouse will be using a large format inkjet printer, id say Epson, HP or Canon.

Assuming the printer is reasonably new (IE < 4 years) it will almost definitely use good inks - in Epson's case UltraChrome. IF the print shop uses a constant feed ink system (after-market) personally id steer clear as they could well be cheap crap inks off ebay which will fade in weeks.
Note: you wont get a choice of ink - you will get what they use!

A GOOD printer will accept nearly any format, but for photographs we prefer TIFF, or 100% quality JPG.

If they are any good at what they do they will have a dedicated computer for their print system (s) and they will have a fully calibrated monitor. get them to show you the image on their screen - BECAUSE they will have calibrated their complete work-process in such a way that the image on screen looks very close to the printer output - so if there is a green cast because your monitor was a bit off, then that is how it will come out.

Yes most good printers will check the image for you before printing and highlight any issues, most will be happy to do minor tweaks to colours but will get you to view/sign off the changes before print.

I would go with gloss or semi-gloss / lustre paper if its available and get 250GSM+

However you will pay for a good service like this - i would probably charge ITRO £40 for a full quality print of that size on good quality media (Kodak / Epson) with archival inks (UltraChrome K3)

If you want to pay £5, then expect "a print" !

Comment: Good to get advice with experience. The shop I use also makes a proof print quickly before any making any large-format prints. That lets you see any color and contrast issue. You get a time to pickup the proof and then a day or two after that for the full-size print.

Comment: Some shops *do* offer a choice of inks! It's called "we have two printers," ha!

Comment: Yes I used to do a few tester prints and mini (say 6x4 ) proofs, its always good to sacrifice a bit of ink on spare paper before committing a to a full print.

Comment: @DanWolfgang - well yes...! (i could see that coming..) but most professional printers that specialise in art reproduction and photographic printing will have A system dedicated to that use. they may have several printers but only one dedicated to the requested type of print.

Comment: What about 8 bits per channel vs 16 bits? TIFF, as long as I'm aware, supports 16 bits, but JPEG, even 100% only supports 16 bit in very few environments. (I guess no print shop supports it.) Does 8 bpc vs 16 bpc make a difference when printing in professional printing shops? (I could only found [this thread](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8002/6294) mentioning "10 bit per color," but the OP was not looking for a print shop)

Comment: @Alberto - yes it can make a (very slight) difference in final rendition - however dont forget that most cameras only save to RAW as 12 or 14 bit, unless you get up to your hasselblad H4D etc at 16 bit. 
As we all know up-sampling (or whatever you want to call it) from an 8 bit to 16 bit will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 5):

The most important question:

**Where is the cough syrup?**

If they answer... *leave.*

If they look at you as if you are an alien, you are in the right place.

Comment: Speaking of cough syrup...

Comment: (To translate: quality prints probably don't come from the drug store.)

Comment: @mattdm's translation makes sense; I had no clue what cmason was talking about. An edited answer to make this more obvious would be helpful.

Comment: Geez, no humor around here...lighten up

Comment: @cmason It could be a cultural thing. There are people living in other countries too, to whom your comment doesn't make any sense because the drug stores doesn't process photos.

Comment: Ah, great answer. ;D Educational, and entertaining to boot. +1

Comment: @cmason I post a lot on stackoverflow.com, and I've learned that humor doesn't go very far with most members, and it may not be because the comment isn't funny, but more so to prevent it from being relevant to the original question. Personally, I've got no issue with it, but in most cases, even a silly comment, gets down-voted...I agree, folks should lighten up,

Answer (score 3):

Talk to the printer. If this is a good shop, they'll not only have answers for you, but will also be able to give you other pointers or advice about things you might not have considered. One that leaps to mind for me: sharpening recommendations.

Comment: I just called a shop, the guy said PDF for format, gloss or matte finish, no choice for ink, and that's pretty much it. I asked about color profiles, and he said he didn't know what they were; red flag?

Comment: Yep, red flag, IMO.

Comment: lots of red flags!! But i will say: you wont get a "Choice" of ink - you will get what they use - the only choice is using a different print shop :-)

Comment: My guess is that this particular flag indicates that the printer doesn't normally do photographs. Try asking about Pantone colors and see what you get back.

Comment: Yes. Avoid that shop. The store where I teach also has a print shop and not only do they have and accept profiles, they also run a calibration loop 3 times a day to account for changes in humidity.

Answer (score 2):

The Ink, Paper and Color Correction should all be on the printers calling card.  They should have that process down so you dont have to think about...  unless you really want to think about it and then they should involve you in the process.  Just expect to pay for color revisions and proofing.

What you need to do is provide the highest resolution .TIF or .PSD file possible AND one in the adobeRGB1998 color space.  that last part is crucial.

Jpg's tend to be in sRGB which is a web standard.  adobeRGB is a print standard and basically includes reds and blues that don't theoretically exist in the other space.  The printer will probably convert to this profile if you give them an sRGB and that will instantly change your color.

For more info on Color Spaces you should search/ask another question or refer to Google.

Comment: Actually more green in Adobe RGB. But yeah. :)

Comment: More on color spaces in [tag:color-management]; in specific, this on [sRGB vs Adobe RGB](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14272/1943)